# jQuery, multiple inputs and onBlur

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have 2 inputs. Both are for an "autocomplete". I also have 2 functions that do pretty much the same thing... Each input calls a different function onBlur. The problem is that the second upon selecting a "suggestion" for the second input, it populates the first. What can I do to make the second one populate the second?

There's probably a better way of doing it but my jQuery/Javascript Knowledge is limited and I'm running out of time... Thanks!

The code:

```
function fillLocation(thisValue) {
    $('#location-box').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestionsLocation').fadeOut('fast');", 200);
}

function fillTerms(thisValue) {
    $('#terms-box').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestionsTerms').fadeOut('fast');", 200);
}


<input type="text" name="search_location" id="location-box" value="" onkeyup="suggestLocation(this.value);" onblur="fillLocation();" autocomplete="off" />

<input type="text" name="search_terms" id="terms-box" value="" onkeyup="suggestTerms(this.value);" onblur="fillTerms();" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: I'm confused because you have fillTerms which takes an argument but then in your onblur you are calling fillTerms() with no argument

Comment: And you are referring to elements (`#terms-box`) for which you provided no code. Can you post a more complete code example And maybe refer to the names of the IDs of the elements instead of "first/second input". That would clarify it (at least for me ;)).

Comment: @Felix - I think he means for to refer back to the inputs as the IDs are assigned to the same inputs that are running the functions.

Comment: @patrick: Oh true, thank you... Maybe I am already too tired ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I'm assuming you want to trigger keyup and blur events for both inputs that have similar functionality, and that will both in turn affect the same input.

This would be one way. Bind the events in javascript, not HTML, and run the proper code

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('#location-box,#terms-box')
                    .bind('keyup', function() {
                           // do your keyup thing using $(this)
                           // to refer back to the input
                           //$('body').append($(this).attr('id') + ': keyup<br />');
                           var theValue = $(this).val();
                     }) 
                     .bind('blur', function() {
                           // do your blur thing using $(this)
                           // to refer back to the input
                           //$('body').append($(this).attr('id') + ': blur<br />');
                     })
    });


<input type="text" name="search_location" id="location-box" value="" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="text" name="search_terms" id="terms-box" value="" autocomplete="off" />
```

EDIT:

Uncomment the $('body') lines to see the events in action.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

EDIT: Added to code to the keyup event to retrieve the value